# What does it contain in linux manual's section 9 of Kernel routines

Tags: kernel, manpage

There are 9 sections in Linux manuals. of which, the ninth is `Kernel routines [Non standard]`.

I check my Kubuntu but get no results feedback.

```
$ man -s 9 -k .
.: nothing appropriate.
```

What does it contain usually in within the section 9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `apt-file` on your system, you can check what packages *would* place manpages in section 9:

```
$ apt-file search /usr/share/man/man9 |
    awk -F: '{seen[$1]++} END{for(p in seen) print p ": " seen[p]}'
open-vm-tools: 1
freebsd-manpages: 1934
librheolef-dev: 1
ax25-tools: 3
```

By far the majority are from the `freebsd-manpages` package, whose description is

> ```
> Description: Manual pages for a GNU/kFreeBSD system
>  This package contains a selection of manual pages from FreeBSD that are useful on a GNU/kFreeBSD system:
>   2 = System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
>   4 = Special files (usually found in /dev)
>   9 = Kernel routines
> ```

So, unless you are running a [GNU/kFreeBSD port](https://www.debian.org/ports/kfreebsd-gnu/), you should not expect to see any kernel routine manpages in Section 9.

Comment: Just curios - why almost the same search does not work [on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=xenial&section=all&arch=any&keywords=usr%2Fshare%2Fman%2Fman9&searchon=contents)?

Comment: @N0rbert that's a good question - I don't know...